# Which version of RabbitMQ is Spring AMQP 3.0.10 compatible with?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We are currently using RabbitMQ version 3.11.2 . Can I safely use Spring AMQP 3.0.10 in my Spring Boot application ? I need help in understanding the compatibility matrix/ rules. Thanks.

Comment: It is not so much the RabbitMQ version as more the amqp java library that is in use.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum . Spring AMQP 3.0.10 uses Java client library version is 5.16.1.  Now I need to find out which version of RabbitMQ is supported by this java client library.

Comment: Since 3.12.x is the latest line, I would not expect any problems with 3.11.x; you should really ask on the rabbitmq-users Google Group, but I am sure they will encourage you to upgrade to the latest.